# Bash Script - How to automate a nano command?

Tags: bash, nano

How can I edit a file saved on a remote server (from Terminal) not using nano command?

Here the code to inject

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/opt/lib/python2.5/site-packages')
```

I tried to solve this problem of writing not using nano command using wget+cat to file location and it seems to work.

```
wget https://REMOTE_SERVER_URL/HTTPRequest.py
cat HTTPRequest.py > /opt/share/pyload/module/network/HTTPRequest.py
```

But there are some errors here, after the script correctly saves "pyload"

```
wget https://REMOTE_SERVER_URL/pyload
cat pyload > /etc/init.d/pyload
chmod 755 /etc/init.d/pyload
```

It then says

```
update-rc.d: warning: /etc/init.d/pyload missing LSB information
update-rc.d: see <http://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts>
 Adding system startup for /etc/init.d/pyload ...
   /etc/rc0.d/K20pyload -> ../init.d/pyload
   /etc/rc1.d/K20pyload -> ../init.d/pyload
   /etc/rc6.d/K20pyload -> ../init.d/pyload
   /etc/rc2.d/S20pyload -> ../init.d/pyload
   /etc/rc3.d/S20pyload -> ../init.d/pyload
   /etc/rc4.d/S20pyload -> ../init.d/pyload
   /etc/rc5.d/S20pyload -> ../init.d/pyload
```

EDIT23NOV: cleared the code

Comment: it may not affect things, but a proper first line is `#!/bin/bash` (without the trailing `#` char). Also, you have to be much more specific about "it doesn't work". Any error messages? Or just file not transfered is your only symptom? But pluse-uno for obviously trying to solve your problem. Good Q. and Good luck.

Comment: This is not an error message of ``wget``, is a warning message and the normal output of ``update-rc.d``, 4 rows below in the script. Enable bash debug mode with ``#!/bin/bash -x`` at the top, so you will see the commands and the output of them below

Comment: `sed: can't read opt/share.....` don't you want `/opt/share/...` ? Good luck.

Comment: Please do not deface your question.

Comment: Questions should include **the shortest code necessary to recreate the problem**. You only need the code that calls nano itself, not all this other cruft around it. See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `nano`, you can use `sed`, could be something like

```
sed -i '/import pycurl/i \
import sys \
sys.path.append("/opt/lib/python2.5/site-packages")' opt/share/pyload/module/network/HTTPRequest.py
```

I didn't test it so maybe you should escape the slashes inside the append.

And first, do a backup of the file because the `-i` modifier will overwrite your file

Comment: No problem, can you tell me where are you having problems? I have just tried using the sed command as i posted and it worked perfectly